# With Django, is there a way to skip locked rows when performing an update?

Tags: django, postgresql

I can do `MyModel.objects.select_for_update(skip_locked=True)` to grab rows that aren't locked.

*However*, if I try to append an `.update(some_field='whatever')` to that, the UPDATE will sill apply to the FULL result set, including locked rows, and it will wait until the locked rows are freed up before executing (i.e. the `select_for_update(skip_locked=True)` portion is ignored in the `update` SQL that is sent).

The SQL, in that scenario, will look like:  `UPDATE "my_model" SET "some_field" = 'whatever'`

I can get around this by first grabbing the IDs of the rows to update and then sending a separate query to update the rows:

```
ids_to_update = list(MyModel.objects.select_for_update(skip_locked=True).values_list('id', flat=True)
MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=ids_to_update).update(some_field='whatever')
```

However,

1. that requires 2 hits to the DB instead of 1 (I'm sure there's a way to do it with 1), and
2. the rows that I'm updating, for the task at hand, have hundreds of thousands to millions of matches, so the 2-step approach is very memory-unfriendly and has high failure potential.

Is there a non-raw-sql means of obtaining what I'm after with Django?  If I have to resort to raw sql, what would that look like?

Comment: Why not just pass the task to an asynchronous task manager, like `celery`? This can wait until all locked rows are freed up.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It is in a celery task. Even in a celery task, databases will time out.